# How to automatically refresh a page and redirects to login page when session has expired (PHP)

Tags: php, session, authentication, reload, logout

Please excuse me, I know there are some questions on stack overflow regarding this, but I don't find any solution that suits my problem. I've a problem, when the session is expired the page is not reloading automatically. Please help. Thank You! Any help would be appreciated.

This is the code I've tried, `$_SESSION['created'] = time();`

```
if((time() - $_SESSION['created']) > 600) {
    header("Refresh: 1;url='logout.php'");
} else {
    $_SESSION['created'] = time();
}
```

Comment: remove the single quotes in url parameter header("Refresh: 1;url=logout.php");

Comment: put this code into all the page top when ever you navigate the all page while session expired means it will redirect to logout.php

Comment: @JYoThI not like that, when ever the session is expired it should automatically redirect to login page.

Comment: @JYoThI Even thought I'm on the same page, it should be redirected to login page if the session is expired

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per your need you have to check the session each seconds once session is valid or not in server side so do something like this.

1) Created a javascript and ajax for checking a session is expired or not in server side each seconds once

2) session.php page to check the valid session or not

3) Then return the 1 or -1 based on that trigger the location.reload() function it automatically moved to logout.php because your top condition become true now.

**session.php**

```
        <?php

            session_start();


            if(!isset( $_SESSION['created'] ) || (time() - $_SESSION['created']) > 600) {

                session_destroy();

                echo "-1";

            } else {

                echo "1";

            }

        ?>
```

Paste this javascript in each and every page

**Java Script :**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">

                function session_checking()
                {
                    $.post( "session.php", function( data ) {

                        if(data == "-1")
                        {
                            alert("Your session has been expired!");
                            location.reload();
                        }

                    });
                }

                var validateSession = setInterval(session_checking, 1000);

    </script>
```

This code should be each page top

```
if(!isset( $_SESSION['created'] ) || (time() - $_SESSION['created']) > 600)   {
header("Refresh: 1;url=logout.php");
} else {
$_SESSION['created'] = time();
}
```

Comment: Thank you it's working, but I've a small problem, if someone stays on the same page without navigating to other page or reload the page it's consider idle. The session is not expiring until and unless he navigates to any other page.

Comment: no no its working in all the case . because the javascript checking the session each and every seconds if expired means it will reload the current page using location.reload(); so that page automitically reload and now your top if condition become true and page redirect into logout.php did you understand ?

Comment: I've tried Jyothi, and facing that problem thats why I mentioned.

Comment: did you ever get this alert("Your session has been expired!");  alert ? @e-Designary   but the logic is work nice for me that's why i suggest you

Comment: I'm not getting alert() only when I stays on the index page without navigating to any other page...in others cases it is okay...this is the only case I'm facing the problem.

Comment: Yes it is on all my pages

Comment: put else part on this if(data == "-1")
                        {
                            alert("Your session has been expired!");
                            location.reload();
                        } else { alert("session not expired"); }   to check the function calling each seconds once or not

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126382/discussion-between-jyothi-and-e-designary).